# How to handle unreachable code in Python in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm, unreachable-code

I am trying to check an ascending or descending trend in a list. If the trend is ascending I want it to print "Buy" else print "Sell".

This is for a python program for trend analysis.
PS- I am new to coding

```
adi = ta.acc_dist_index(high, low, close, volume, fillna=False)
a = adi[-1]

ADI = adi[-7:]
vol_status_adi = ""

if a <=100:
def order():  # For ascending
    for i in range(len(ADI) - 1):
        if ADI[i] - ADI[i + 1] > 0:
            return False
        return True

if True:
    vol_status_adi = "Buy"
else:
    vol_status_adi = "Sell" --- unreachable code
print("ADI signal is: ", vol_status_adi)
```

expected output '''ADI signal is: But/Sell'''

actual output ''' ADI signal is: '''

Comment: if True: will always execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`True` always evaluates to `True`. Looks like maybe your intent was to use the boolean value returned from the `order` method to change the contents of the printed string in which case you need

```
if order():
    vol_status_adi = "Buy"
else:
    vol_status_adi = "Sell" --- unreachable code
print("ADI signal is: ", vol_status_adi)
```